# USB bluetooth in Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual Box

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, virtualbox, windows-7-x64

I have my UBUNTU 12.04 installed in virtual box on my windows 7. The problem seems to be that the ubuntu system does not detect the bluetooth usb device. I have installed bluetooth on ubuntu ,I opened it and there I cant see my USB bluetooth device. Any suggestions?Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install bluetooth manager(blueman) in your virtual machine.
then check for the bluetooth icon on top right corner.

Comment: tried that but even then it didnt help.says adapter not found.Not able to connect to my android device